# Converting dynamic URLs to static ones

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

convert my dynamic url to static :

```
https://registratsiyaooo.by/blog/?_page=2
```

my .htaccess rule now dont work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/_page/([^/]*)$ /blog/?_page=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please do mention which URL you are hitting in browser and from which url you want to serve it from backend for more clarity on your question please.

Comment: And "does not work" means what _exactly_ ? What happens if you request something like `https://example.com/blog/_pages/17`? Where did you implement that rule? And how did you make sure that the rule gets processed (considered) at all by the http server?